# Migration : Two foreign key referenced to the same table result to error

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-5.7

I tried to build a blog and i'm blocked due to an error in the migration of one table.

I've tried to change the order of foreign key creation,

to build the two foreign key into only one with array,

```
$table->foreign(['commentary_id', 'post_id'])->references(['id', 'post_id'])->on('commentaries');
```

Commentaries Migration

```
$table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('id')->unsigned();
$table->string('content');
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->timestamps();

$table->primary(['post_id', 'id']);
$table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Responses Migration

```
$table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('commentary_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('id')->unsigned();
$table->string('content');
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->timestamps();

$table->primary(['post_id', 'commentary_id', 'id']);
$table->foreign(['commentary_id', 'post_id'])->references(['id', 'post_id'])->on('commentaries');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

And the error that i got :

```
General error: 1005 Can't create table `blog-lurius`.`responses` 
(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") 
(SQL: alter table `responses` add constraint `responses_commentary_id_post_id_foreign` foreign key (`commentary_id`, `post_id`) references `commentaries` (`id`, `post_id`))
```

I expect to doesn't have a fatal error in my migration. Where my two foreign key are both effective.

Comment: $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade'); Try add these behind.

Comment: The problem hasn't with user_id... and like i just say, i "find" the problem but i can't explain why i got one...

Comment: The sequence of the parameter is important as mentioned from the documents. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#foreign-key-constraints